# Rails3 phonegap jsonp method override PUT,POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova, cross-domain, jsonp, rack

I am trying to create a phone gap app using the rails 3 rest api. Because of the cross domain i have to use JSONP which only allows GET. But is rails you can put _method=POST in the form action to override the method

I also need to override the rack middleware MehtodOVerride with my own custom middleware to allow it.

So I created a lib/restful_jsonp_middleware.rb with following code

```
module Rack

class RestfulJsonpMiddleware

  HTTP_METHODS = %w(GET HEAD PUT POST DELETE OPTIONS)
  METHOD_OVERRIDE_PARAM_KEY = "_method".freeze
  HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER = "HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE".freeze

  attr_accessor :method_parameter_name

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
    @method_parameter_name = METHOD_OVERRIDE_PARAM_KEY
  end

  # We check if the method parameter is in the request
  # and set up the request to allow the execution of the
  # overwritten HTTP method
  def call(env)
    req = Request.new(env)
    method = req.params[@method_parameter_name]
    method = method.to_s.upcase
    if HTTP_METHODS.include?(method)
      env["rack.methodoverride.original_method"] = env["REQUEST_METHOD"]
      env["REQUEST_METHOD"] = method
      env[HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER] = method
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
end
```

Also I added these lines to my application.rb file

```
require 'lib/restful_jsonp_middleware.rb'
config.middleware.swap Rack::MethodOverride,Rack::RestfulJsonpMiddleware
```

Now if i do rack middleware i am getting this error

```
rake aborted!
```

cannot load such file -- lib/restful_jsonp_middleware.rb
/home/sunny/workspace/ruby_projects/jquery_bootstrap/config/application.rb:4:in `require'
/home/sunny/workspace/ruby_projects/jquery_bootstrap/config/application.rb:4:in`'
/home/sunny/workspace/ruby_projects/jquery_bootstrap/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/sunny/workspace/ruby_projects/jquery_bootstrap/Rakefile:5:in`'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in`load_rakefile'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in`block in load_rakefile'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in`load_rakefile'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`standard_exception_handling'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in`'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in`'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/sunny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`'

What am I doing wrong.

Can anyone please help me

Comment: I would use CORS for this instead of JSONP. Here's a really good resource: http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428